# When i added missing dll and ran regsvr32 name_of_dll.dll it shown me weird message

Tags: api, dll, module, ocx

So

1. I downloaded game, and it shown me that API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL is missing in my computer
2. I downloaded missing dll file from dll-files.com (i downloaded right one (64 bit))
3. I found tutorial how to add it so i can try to run the game, I've found different methods how to add it, tried every1 but it still didnt work for me.
4. It started to showing me something different "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
5. i tried to fix that problem, so i did that: "Click Start then Run and type in "regsvr32 name_of_dll.dll" and hit enter."
6. It shown me: "The module "api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll" was not loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
   Make sure that "api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.
7. I gave up in this moment. btw i have Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit OS

Comment: i see that it doesnt show pictures so i will just write it there: The module "api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again. Im just lost there and i gave up, so im trying it there. (btw the problem is that i cant run one game cuz of missing dll file.)

Comment: What does that error have to do with Java? Without any context, how can anyone help you?

Comment: Hello. Please use [edit] option to correct or add relevant information to the question. Don't use comments for that (not everyone willing to help you will also be willing to read entire conversation just to find all crucial parts needed to answer your questions. Those should be in the question itself).